# How do I modify the configuration of Yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

In `npm` I can run

```
npm config set cafile "path/to/my/cert.pem"
```

Can you do something similar with Facebook's `yarn`?

When I run `yarn -h`, I don't see any options for setting any kind of configuration.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the same syntax to set a config value in `yarn`:

`yarn config set cafile "path/to/my/cert.pem"`

Although, if you have this set in your `npm` config already, it should fall through and use what has been set there. You could therefore have different `cafile` config values for `yarn` and `npm`.

If you run `yarn help` you'll see all the yarn commands. Running `yarn -h` is currently the same as running `yarn install help`, hence why you don't see the config or any other commands. There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/740) to make `yarn -h` and `yarn --help` equivalent to `yarn help` as it is in `npm`.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie. I wouldn't have thought there were multiple helps to look at.